# Change schema location in wsdl

Tags: c#, wcf

I have the below config in my web.config for WCF.

```
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
```

So once I do this I will get schema location in wsdl as

```
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://mysever/Projectname/Services/myService?xsd=xsd0" namespace="MyServiceHost/Service/01/2011"/>
```

But i want to change that to **https**://mysever/Projectname/Services/myService?xsd=xsd0.

I cannot enable httpsGetEnabled = true as i will be getting wsdl through http, but i wanted to have the service requests in https.

I am using a loadbalancer, where loadbalancer to webservers traffic is over http.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest to use [WCFExtras](http://wcfextras.codeplex.com/) ([HOWTO](http://wcfextras.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=HowToUse&referringTitle=Home)) or [WCFExtrasPlus](http://wcfextrasplus.codeplex.com/).

How to use ECFExtras:

1. Add following extension to the config file

   ```
   <extensions>
     <behaviorExtensions>
       <add
         name="wsdlExtensions"
         type="WCFExtras.Wsdl.WsdlExtensionsConfig, WCFExtras, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral"
       />
     </behaviorExtensions>
   </extensions>
   ```
2. Add custom behavior

   ```
   <behavior name="CustomBehavior">
     <wsdlExtensions location="https://mysever/Projectname/Services/myService.svc"/>
   </behavior>
   ```

Also you can use [SoapExtensionReflector](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2005/11/16/493496.aspx).

Moreover you would need to add the following [attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.addressfiltermode.aspx) to the service declaration ot be able to use the service through the load balancer.

```
[ServiceBehavior(AddressFilterMode = AddressFilterMode.Any)]
```

Comment: I am trying this, will mark this answer once it is done. Thanks